# How to perform a check on ng-disabled in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wizard, fuelux

I am using a [fuelUX Wizard](http://exacttarget.github.com/fuelux/#wizard) and Angularjs. I would like the next button to be enabled or disabled basing on this controller method:

```
$scope.canMoveForward = function(){
        switch($("#moduleWizard").wizard("selectedItem").step){
            case 1:
            //check if the module on the first step is valid*/  
                return $scope.validSelection && $scope.linkedPredicateForm.$valid;

            case 2:
            //check if the table is empty
                return !linkingDataSource.isEmpty();

            case 3:
                var enab= ($scope.saveModeForm.$valid && $scope.newSourceForm.$valid) || 
                ($scope.saveModeForm.$valid && $scope.appendSourceForm.$valid)
        }
    };
```

So indeed this is how I decleared the buttons:

```
<div class="actions">
                <button class="btn btn-mini btn-prev" ng-click="refresh()"> <i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>Prev</button>
                <button class="btn btn-mini btn-next" data-last="Finish"  id="wizard-next" ng-disabled="!canMoveForward()"
                        ng-click="handleStepResult()">
                    Next<i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>
            </div>
```

And it works fine, except when I get back from the second page to the first page: if the next button is disabled in the second page it will be this way even on the first page, unless I don't edit the form there. Is there anyway to refresh the ng-disabled binding?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess AngularJS cannot check if the output of `canMoveForward()` has changed or not. I found that for this kind of things it's easier to rely on scope variables. You could do something like this:

```
ng-disabled="!canMoveForward"
```

Then in your controller just set the property to true/false as needed:

```
$scope.canMoveForward = false;
```

Comment: very true.Setting a variable works smoothly.Just call the function to variable and return true or false from that function.+1 for that

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem and I've discovered that the problem is with the `!` operator.

This fails:

```
ng-disabled="!canMoveForward()"
```

But this will work:

```
ng-disabled="canNotMoveForward()"
```

Comment: This seems to work with standalone functions, but not with methods.

Comment: I can't get the wizard to render with the proper css styling. I am also using AngularJS. 
Can you help me with loading the appropriate css and js files ? And also how to render the wizard ?
thanks.