# How do you disable the submit button after a single click to prevent multiple submissions in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've looked all over the web including several stack overflow examples for a solution to the question.  To be specific, I tried this:

```js
var disableButton = function() {
  document.getElementById('<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
}

$scope.isDisabled = false;
var someFunc = function() {
  $scope.isDisabled = true;
}
```

```html
<button OnClientClick="disableButton()" type="submit">Submit</button>
<button ng-disabled="isDisabled" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Neither worked as advertised. Any other suggestions? Please Angular suggestions only.  Thank you.

Comment: Is this to get the button 'disabled' or just to prevent from sending? You are making the button disabled with that angular function, but why don't you check to see if !$scope.isDisabled on your other function?

Comment: Modify your someFun like this $scope.someFun = function() {}

Comment: Good look, $scope.someFun is the right way and I tried it. It did not fix the problem though.

Comment: I want the button to submit once and only once. That's all. It call $scope.someFunc(); once that is done, it should be able to submit multiple times.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You were very close to the answer. The only thing you missed out was calling the `someFunc()` function on button using `ng-click`.

The other issue is, in your controller the function should be `$scope.someFunc()` and not `var someFunc()`

**Working example:**
Your index.html should be like:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="application.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="demo" ng-controller="demoController">
          <button type="submit" ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-click="disableButton()"> Click me to disable myself</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

And your controller application.js be like:

```
angular.module('demo', [])
    .controller('demoController',function($scope){

    $scope.isDisabled = false;

    $scope.disableButton = function() {
        $scope.isDisabled = true;
    }

    });
```

Comment: Ya, I tried this and my submit (not ng-click) function calls my function where $scope.isDisabled = true; is on the first line inside the function and $scope.isDisabled = false is on the outside of the function.   My button is as displayed above as submit.

Comment: Okay. So is it working? If not, can you provide me with a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co) link of your code so that we can look into it?

Comment: @rashadb I've updated the above code with button type as "submit". I hope this helps.

Comment: this doesn't fire the submit form in asp.net.

Comment: The angular property $submitted becomes false when the button is disabled like this which may cause you issues depending on implementation.

Answer (score 12):

Another way is to write a directive which disables the submit button

```
    angular.module('myApp').directive('clickedDisable', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs){
            $(ele).click(function(){
                $(ele).attr('disabled', true);
            });
        }
    };
```

And in the HTML

```
    <button type="submit" clicked-disable></button>
```

Comment: what is $ here? Jquery?

Comment: technically speaking its jqLite unless you're also loading jquery in which case jquery actually takes over the $.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't like any of the provided answers as they all clutter the global scope with the `isDisabled` variable, why not do it this way instead?

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="disableButton($event)">Submit</button>
```

.

```
$scope.disableButton = function($event) {
    $event.currentTarget.disabled = true;
};
```

---

if if you need to submit a form before the disable.

**this code is not tested**

```
<form ng-submit="disableFormSubmitButton($event)">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

.

```
$scope.disableFormSubmitButton = function($event) {
    $($event).find('[type=submit]').prop('disabled',true);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="email" ng-disabled="button" required ng-init="button=true">
<a class="btn" ng-click="button=false">enable edit</a>
<a class="btn" ng-click="button=true">disable edit</a>
<a class="btn" ng-click="button=!button">toggle edit</a>
```

Also there are different approaches to achieve this functionality, you can go through following links, they will surely help.

[disabling all form controls between submit and server response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21638542/4373895)

[disable button on $http/$q calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22720438/4373895)

[how to perform a check on ng-disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17083781/4373895)

Comment: I look over all of these before asking the question. Most of these are a bit too much for my use case. I have a simple form with three inputs and a submit button. Most examples come with ng-click. I need type="submit" for my button.

Comment: @rashadb AngularJS is mostly used for single page applications, and in such cases you should not use the "submit" action, and better handle the form submission through Ajax using Angular $http

Answer (score 1):

Find the working example also.

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="DisableButtonApp">
        <div ng-controller="MyAppCtrl">
            <button ng-click="someFunc()" ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-model="isDisabled"type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </body>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('DisableButtonApp', [])
    .controller('MyAppCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.isDisabled = false;
    $scope.someFunc = function(){
        alert("Clicked!");
        $scope.isDisabled = true;
        return false;
    };
}]);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rtax5/258/)

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you can do that directly in the template:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app>

  <button ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-click="isDisabled=true" type="submit">Submit</button> isDisabled={{isDisabled}}

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I got to work for my single form submission scenario:

```
$scope.increment = 0;
$scope.someFunc = function() {
     $scope.increment++
     if($scope.increment > 1) {
          return;
     } else {
          //do something else
   }
}
```

No directives or HTMl necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Because of historical reasons single  (or ) inside  submits form if type is not 'submit'.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), button can may have type attribute.

```
<button type="button">Your button</button>
```

makes button have no default behavior.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932657/1390039) is more detailed answer.

Answer (score -1):

Add `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isDisabled">` and add ***isDisabled*** in ng-disabled attribute `ng-disabled="isDisabled"` , so when you select checkbox button is disabled and deselect checkbox, enable button.

Please see link http://plnkr.co/edit/e3w54TZEmfj8h5O6BX7B?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-click="isDisabled=true">Hochladen</button> isDisabled={{isDisabled}}
</body>
```