# Prevent a button from being clicked twice in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working in angularjs and am new to it, I have made an app using this.

There are a few pages in my app, now my problem is i am having two buttons which navigate to other pages, but my issue is when i click on a button (span), it opens the same page twice.

Can anyone please help me how to solve this?
My code is as below:

**javascript**

```
  $scope.foo = function() {
        if ($scope.filterflg !== "1" ) {
            $scope.filterflg = "1";
             $scope.disabled = true;


            gallery.pushPage("filter.html", {
                params: FkCategory
            });

            $timeout(function() {
                console.log("====timeout occured===");
                $scope.filterflg = "0";
                  $scope.disabled = false;
            }, 3000);
        }
    };
```

**html**

```
<ons-button  id="test1" class="toolbar-button--quiet navigation-bar__line-height"  ng-click="isProcessing=true;foo()" ng-model ="filterflg"
         style="border: none; padding: 0 5px 0 0; margin-right:7px ;">
            <i class="ion-android-options" style="font-size:24px; color: #FFFFFF;"></i>
        </ons-button>
```

I have wasted 10 days on this issue, hope some buddy will help me to save my job..! :(

Comment: This probably may help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984581/how-do-you-disable-the-submit-button-after-a-single-click-to-prevent-multiple-su

Comment: You can use the "ng-disabled". Just make a scope function with for example 
ng-disabled="isDisabled"

Comment: Is your function `foo()` is calling twice? Why did you use `timer`?

Comment: Timer is not a good way to further enable the button. Your page may take more time to load even more than 3000 mili seconds

Comment: @AbhilashPA - i want to prevent this button to navigate to page twice

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh - so please help me by another solution

Comment: @OleReidarHolm - i have used with no luck..can you please tell what changes should i make?

Comment: @FireCandy for that you need to update your question with those details. What is gallery? how is pushPage is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the span to a button element and disable that button without  `$timeout` just after first click

```
 $scope.foo = function() {
        just simply 
        $scope.disabled = false;
        // Your other code 


 };
```

or use a flag to check page is already open or not will solve your problem

```
 $scope.isFilteropen = false;

 $scope.foo = function() {
     if ($scope.isFilteropen == false) {
         $scope.isFilteropen = true;
        // your other code 
     }
 };
```

Comment: And what changes in my html?

Comment: <span ng-click="isProcessing=true;foo()"></span> to  <button ng-click="isProcessing=true;foo()"></button>

Comment: could you create a fiddle with your problem , my solution works fine check it here http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20051/

Comment: Hello brother,you did what i exactly want but can we re enable when we come back to that page from page stack as its an app

Comment: yes i know button re enable automatically when  we back on page, because when we back on page controller  also recalled  and $scope.disabled = false; make button re enable

Comment: actually i am using onsen ui for this app,and which maintaing a page stack in anvigator,so when we come back no controller is calling..got my point?

Comment: Than simple timeout work look at this http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20054/ but i am not aware of onsen ui that's why i ask you for a fiddle

Comment: thank you sharma ji ... :) can you please help me on one more question,its also weird..!

Comment: Have you ever used Onsen ui?if yes then you know it provide a default back button and its navigator maintains a page stack,Now my problem is when i click more than one time it says "pagestack is empty" and my app stopped working..it only happens when i click very fast and twice on back button.can you suggest any solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

ng-disabled doesn't work on span. It only works for **input** or **button** types.

you have two options -

1. convert the span to a button element
2. use a variable like $scope.isProcessing to wrap the foo() function.

   $scope.foo = function() {

   ```
   if (!$scope.isProcessing) {     
       //...       
       $timeout(function() {
            console.log("====timeout occured===");
            $scope.filterflg = "0";
            $scope.disabled = false;
            $scope.isProcessing = false;        
       }, 3000);
    }
   ```

   };

**html**

```
<span ng-click="isProcessing=true;foo()"></span>
```

Comment: And what changes have to made in html?

Comment: Please see the updated question..which is still not working..:(

Comment: did you add the if (!$scope.isProcessing) check ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
<span class="toolbar-button--quiet navigation-bar__line-height" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="disabled=true;foo();disabled=false;" ng-model ="filterflg"> </span>
```

And remove your `timer` from the function `Foo()`.

Comment: hello used this.still it goes two time next page..:(..please brother..help me..please see my update question

Comment: @firecandy, did you debug your function to know what is the reason to load your page twice?